# Robotframework: How to build proper keyword with embedded variable which defines number next parameters?

Tags: robotframework

I'll try to do my best in explanation of my new issue.
I have to build keyword which should include 2 variables:

1. number of elements to check,
2. list of these elements with description.

Example of such a keyword:

```
Check number all elements and names and the url each of them [3, "element1 /img/el1.jpg element2 /img/el2.jpg element3 /img/el3.jpg"]
```

Put simply: I have to check first if I have 3 elements, and next check properties name and url of each element.

Those properties seem to be like "list", am I right?
Do you have any ideas how to solve my issue?

Comment: What is one "element"? Is it a string with a name and a path? When you say "check properties name and url", what does that mean? What are you checking for? How do you know that "element1 /img/el1.jpg" is valid? Is it because that both contain the number "1"? Also, is there a reason this has to be one keyword instead of two -- one to check the number, and one to check each value in the list?

Comment: @BryanOakley, I've tried to answer below Pekka's comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You are close to solution, you need to use a list. Because Robot Framework knows list length, you don't need to give it as a parameter.

Here is one possible solution:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Keywords ***
Check Elements
    [arguments]    ${elementlist}
    ${listlen}=    Get Length    ${elementlist}
    ${pairs}=      Evaluate    ${listlen} / 2
    :FOR    ${element}    IN RANGE    ${pairs}
    \    ${element}       Remove From List    ${elementlist}    0
    \    ${description}   Remove From List    ${elementlist}    0
    \    Log     Check element and description here

*** Test Cases ***
ListTest
    @{elementlist}=    Create List    element1   /img/el1.jpg   element2   /img/el2.jpg   element3  /img/el3.jpg
    Check Elements    ${elementlist}
```

Comment: Now I'm closer to solve my issue, but... I need to give the number before the list to do double check - the first: I have proper number of all elements and the second: they all have proper values.

Comment: and one more question - is there any way to create such a list with elements directly in keyword, like I've been written in my first post?

Comment: If your elements are separated by space, you should be able to use "Split String" keyword like this: @{elementlist}=    Split String    element1 /img/el1.jpg element2 /img/el2.jpg element3 /img/el3.jpg. Split String is in String library

Comment: But is there any way to create keyword like this: Check number all elements and names and the url each of them [3, "element1 /img/el1.jpg element2 /img/el2.jpg element3 /img/el3.jpg"]? I have list declaration in keyword at once. Is it possible? And next - becuase of no possibilty using "nested for" how should I check if elements number from list (after first variable in keyword - 3) is equal 3 (first variable value)?

Comment: I don't understand what "Check number" part of keyword means. Can you update your question and write in pseudocode what you want to happen?

Comment: I have web page, which contains of 3 clickable elements. For other case, it may contain other number of the elements. Each element has its own name and other properties. I have to check:
1. if this page contains of declared (by me) number elements (the first declared variable),
2. if each element's name and other properties (from the second variable) are the same (on the page and from second variable)
It has to be in one final keyword, to check expected and actual results.